# What does "LL-NDK" (in Android Project Treble) mean?

Tags: android

Android 8.0 re-architected the Android OS framework (in a project known as **Treble**) to make it easier, faster, and less costly for manufacturers to update devices to a new version of Android.
Google restricts that only **stable** system native libraries are exposed to vendors, e.g. [LL-NDK](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/vndk) Libraries are Framework Shared Libraries that are known to be stable. Their developers are committed to maintain their API/ABI stabilities.

Anyone knows the meaning of **"LL-NDK"**? what does **"LL"** short for?

Comment: According to [this comment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/test/vts-testcase/vndk/+/refs/heads/master/dependency/VtsVndkDependencyTest.py#48) in the Vendor Test Suite, it stands for **L**ow-**L**evel.

Comment: @Michael Thanks, it looks reasonable :)